# React-native fetch method response json contains another json

Tags: android, json, react-native

I'm trying to basically extract errcode from this json which I received from fetch

`{
04-20 13:59:21.982  1655  1825 I ReactNativeJS:   "token" : "36b95550-f782-4efc-b96d-2cefa3c9fc3f",
04-20 13:59:21.982  1655  1825 I ReactNativeJS:   "error" : {
04-20 13:59:21.982  1655  1825 I ReactNativeJS:     "errcode" : 0
04-20 13:59:21.982  1655  1825 I ReactNativeJS:   }
04-20 13:59:21.982  1655  1825 I ReactNativeJS: }`

now I know response("token") gives the token but response("error") gives an error

```
[TypeError: Object is not a function (evaluating 'jsonResponse("error")')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: The js code which makes the api call

```
fetch(baseUrl, {
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
      email : this.state.Username,
      password : this.state.Password
    })

  })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseText);
    console.log(jsonResponse["token"]);
    //console.log(jsonResponse("error"));
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'MainPage',
      name: 'Login',
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
    Alert.alert(
      'Error',
      'Invalid Username or Password',
      [

        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => {console.log('OK Pressed');

        }},
      ]
    )
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls this?

Comment: Check the edited Question!!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: Thanks man appreciate it !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have used jsonResponse("error") instead of jsonResponse["error"].